# What is the sum of normalized Hermite polynomials divided by $\sqrt{n+\gamma}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, special-functions

Is there any more useful form (integral form, as a delta function, etc.) for the sum
$$
\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}H_n(x)H_n(y)}{2^nn!\sqrt{n+\gamma}},
$$
or for this similar sum
$$
\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}H_n(x)H_n(y)}{2^nn!\sqrt{n+\gamma}}e^{iz\sqrt{n+\gamma}},
$$
where $\gamma$ is a real number?

Other than trying to use the completeness relation,
$$
\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}H_n(x)H_n(y)}{2^nn!}=\sqrt{\pi}\delta(x-y),
$$
the closest I have found was given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792189/summation-involving-hermite-polynomials) where it was stated
$$
\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{H_n(x)z^n}{n!\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{exp}\left(2xze^{-t^2}-z^2e^{-2t^2}-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)dt.
$$
Further explanation of this equation would be useful as well.

Comment: You can present the first sum as an integral, using the Mehler's formula - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel

Comment: $$\sqrt\pi\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}H_n(x)H_n(y)}{2^nn!\sqrt{n+\gamma}}=\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}H_n(x)H_n(y)}{2^nn!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda^2(n+\gamma)}d\lambda$$
$$=e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda^2\gamma}d\lambda\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)}{n!}\Big(\frac{e^{-\lambda^2}}{2}\Big)^n$$
$$=e^{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda^2\gamma}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2\lambda^2}}}\exp\Big(-\frac{x^2+y^2-2e^{-\lambda^2}xy}{1-e^{-2\lambda^2}}\Big)d\lambda$$

Comment: Of course, you also have to clarify which form of $H_n(x)$ you use - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials

Comment: I am using the physicists' Hermite polynomials

Comment: Should the last line read: $=e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda^2\gamma}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2\lambda^2}}}\exp\Big(-\frac{e^{-2\lambda^2}(x^2+y^2)-2e^{-\lambda^2}xy}{1-e^{-2\lambda^2}}\Big)d\lambda$

Comment: It seems the expressions are equivalent

Comment: Any chance anyone knows if integrating this function over a square region around the origin is finite? i.e. $\int_{-l}^{l}\int_{-l}^{l}dxdy e^{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda^2\gamma}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2\lambda^2}}}\exp\Big(-\frac{x^2+y^2-2e^{-\lambda^2}xy}{1-e^{-2\lambda^2}}\Big)d\lambda$

Comment: It looks like the integral converge for any finite area of (x,y) and diverges logarithmically when $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to\infty$. A numeric check could also help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? It appears that the integrand diverges for $\lambda=0$ when $x=y$, and the series expansion in that region goes like $\frac{1}{|\lambda|}$ which is not a convergent integral. I am having trouble showing that this divergence is tamed when integrating over $x$ and $y$ as well.